# XML and JSON -- Advantages and Disadvantages?

Tags: xml, json

I recently heard about JavaScript Object Notation (JSON), and after looking it up, it seems like it's becoming rather popular as an alternative to the Extensible Markup Language (XML).

I went on [this](http://json.org/xml.html) page for more info, but it seemed more of an XML-bashing page rather than a comparison page. So I thought I should ask here:

What are the benefits of JSON as compared to XML, and why (if at all) should we choose one over the other?

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions already: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=json+vs+xml

Comment: Thank god ! this post is not locked.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

- JSON is more compact and can be easily loaded in JavaScript.
- XML is stricter and has support for schemas and namespaces.

On the face of it JSON seems superior in every way - it's flexible, more compact and in many cases easier to use (especially when working with JavaScript), however it lacks some key features, in particular:

- **Schema support**,

I.e. the ability for party A to specify the format of a document, and the ability for party B to check that they are supplying something that matches this format.

This is crucial when passing data between separate systems, where a deviation from the expected format might mean that the data cannot be processed (or worse, is processed incorrectly).

- **Namespace support**,

I.e. the ability to mix data intended to be read by multiple sources (or written by multiple sources) in the same document.

An example of this in action is the [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) protocol - namespaces allow for the separation of the SOAP "Envelope", or "Wrapper" data which is passed alongside the serialised application data.  This allows web frameworks process and handle the SOAP Envelope and then pass the body / payload data onto the application.

---

JSON is very useful when developing a web application where fast, compact and convenient serialisation of data is required, however it's flexible nature is the very thing that makes it less suitable than XML for transferring data between separate systems, or storing data that will be read by 3rd parties.

Perhaps in time these sorts of features will appear in JSON, but for now XML is the dominant format for things like web services and file formats.

Comment: Is JSON actually more compact once both have been compressed?

Comment: There are even cases when xml is shorter than json as you don't need to wrap element sets with an array.  And the ability to have comments in XML is really handy, especially for config files.

Comment: From my experience, JSON also has [schema support](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/), albeit it would usually be provided in an accompanying file. Is there some feature of XML schema that distinguishes it from JSON schema?

Comment: More disadvantages of Json in my opinion: line breaks not supported, comments not supported. These make it unsuitable for stuff like language (localization/i18n) files

Answer (score 26):

**Advantages of JSON**

- Smaller message size
- More structural information in the document

  - Can easily distinguish between the number `1` and the string `"1"` as numbers, strings (and Booleans) are represented differently in JSON.
  - Can easily distinguish between single items and collections of size one (using JSON arrays).
- Easier to represent a null value
- Easily consumed by JavaScript

**Advantages of XML**

- Namespaces allow for sharing of standard structures
- Better representation for inheritance
- Standard ways of expressing the structure of the document:  XML schema, DTD, etc
- Parsing standards:  DOM, SAX, StAX
- Standards for querying: XQuery and XPath
- Standards for transforming a document:  XSLT

**Draw**

- Human Readable
- Easy to parse

Comment: 11 years later, XSLT was the first thing that popped into my mind when I came across my own question again, and somehow you're the only one who's mentioned it. I almost want to unaccept the top answer and accept yours instead...

Answer (score 7):

**XML**

- Can have a schema that states its format.

  - This is of interest to quality control people. You can prove that its format matches what is expected, and therefore you may not have to be quite as fervent as you might otherwise be at checking that a field exists within it every time you want to reference one.
  - (Though this pre-supposes that you go out of your way to actually validate the XML against its schema.)
- Bloated; each field name has to be written out twice per field. Ew!

**JSON**

- Far less bloated, easier to parse and arguably more human readable (if you space it out properly).
- Not quite as powerful: not expressive enough to separate attributes from values.

Comment: In xml you don't need to write the end tag if you have no child elements.  Using attributes and element sets can even allow xml to be shorter than json.  Xml also supports comments.

Comment: @MatthewWhited: Ah but comments have no place in a wire format!

Comment: They may...  If you are making a self describing API, remote configuration or just want human readable metadata comments can be very useful.

Comment: @MatthewWhited: A self-describing API shouldn't need comments ;)

Comment: Good luck with enumerations and other validations.

Comment: @MatthewWhited: Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

**Advantages of XML**

1. Near ubiquitous support in a wide array of languages and frameworks. More likely than not there's already a tool out there to help your extract information from an XML response.
2. It can adhere to a concrete schema if so you choose. Once it validates, you can say it's correct and start parsing.
3. Namespaces allow you to divide the XML.

**Advantages of JSON**

1. Lightweight in comparison to XML. Fewer characters = smaller time going through the `internet tubes`.
2. Easier to handle with Javascript if you need something for a web application.

Answer (score 3):

JSON - smaller and can be natively loaded as JavaScript object (speed is a value)

XML - still standard, however older (slower, bigger, but not only JS)

Comment: JSON is "not only JS", too. Anything can support JSON, regardless of its ancestry.

Comment: @Tomalak - very true, and soon would be everywhere, but originally designed for JS (JavaScript Object Notation)

Comment: JSON was not "designed for" JS. It's a markup language that _derives_ from existing Javascript syntax: specifically, Javascript's notation for object declaration.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is a much simpler format than XML. JSON is intended only for describing data as an object hierarchy, while XML has many other features as well.

If you only need to send plain simple data, then JSON is a good alternative, as that is just what it's intended for.

If you need a more powerful way of describing your data then you would need XML, as JSON simply doesn't do anything fancy.

Answer (score 1):

They're equally expressive formats.  JSON is less verbose.  JSON can be parsed easily in JavaScript (and other languages), and XML is parsed easily by many things too.

I think the most important consideration is what will be consuming the data - if you already have a bunch of XML-interpreting code, stick with that.  If all your clients are web developers, go with JSON.

Comment: Well, XML is much more expressive than JSON, actually. It can for example describe it's own data structure, and it can use namespaces to partition data, features that simply isn't built into JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Less verbose- XML uses more words than necessary

JSON is faster- Parsing XML software is slow and cumbersome. Many of these DOM manipulation libraries can lead to your applications using large amounts of memory due to the verbosity and cost of parsing large XML files.

JSON data model’s structure matches the data: JSON’s data structure is a map whereas XML is a tree. Although a map (just key/value pairs) can be limiting, that’s what we want, because it is easier to interpret and is predictable.

In code: Items are represented the same way in code. In many languages, especially dynamic ones, you can just ‘slurp in the JSON’ and you immediately have your domain object. It is easy to go from objects in JSON to the objects in code because they align. When going from objects in XML to objects in code they do not align and there is a lot of room for interpretation.

JSON is limiting, but that’s a good thing: JSON is limited in terms of what objects can be modeled. Some may think XML is better because more objects can be modeled and it doesn’t prohibit developers. But even though JSON prohibits developers, it is in a positive way, making the code simpler, more predictable, and easy to read. XML can be formatted to look and function any way a company wants, but it makes it difficult for developers to read, understand, and convert.  In most cases people believe XML is better because developers can do anything under the sun but in the age of simplifying, less is more, making JSON a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

### **Abberivation?**

- JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)
- XML (Extensible Markup Language)

### **Usage?**

- Both for data interchange.

### **Best For?**

- JSON when as a storage medium for web applications because of its simplicity.
- XML when transmitting structured data over the web.

### **Why / When XML?**

- More flexible then HTML. ( application this makes it easier to format data and display it correctly in any browser or device )
- Create custom tags that can be used in any XML data. (This makes developers and designers to collaborate when creating new projects)
- It can be used to share structured information between programs and documents.

### **Why / When JSON?**

- It's language-independent. ( The language-independent nature of JSON makes it ideal for use in other web development lanuanges like Ruby and Javascript )
- JSON is also human-readable.
- You can read and write this format without knowing what goes into each field thanks to JSON parser packages.

**Just remember these rules,**

A- Fields must have consistent names.

B- All values must be strings.

C- Comma characters must separate values.

- JSON uses less memory than XML software when processing information (ideal for large data processing).
- JSON has been gaining popularity as a storage medium for web applications because of its simplicity.
- Used in many different contexts, from web development to data storage(also ideal format for sharing information between web APIs and applications).
- It's great for sharing data between multiple applications.

### **Downsides of XML?**

- XML code is a more lengthy way of representing structured data.
- XML is readable by humans but not necessarily by machines.
- XML has some issues when it comes to cross-platform compatibility.
- XML files require more storage space than JSON files.
- XML has a more rigid structure than JSON, making it more difficult to manipulate without breaking the document.

### **Downsides of JSON?**

- XML is more secure than JSON (Research done by NIST).
- Most of the enterprises using XML enviourements rather JSON.

### **Why JSON > XML is Batter Overall:**

- XML is much more difficult to parse than JSON. JSON is parsed into a ready-to-use JavaScript object.

**Like with XML:**

- First Fetch an XML document.
- Use the XML DOM to loop through the document.
- Extract values and store in variables.

**When using JSON:**

- Fetch a JSON string.
- **JSON.Parse** the JSON string.

Hope this detailed explaination helps.