# View Dynamic XMLs as Tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have complex xmls and I want them to view as a tree . I love the way http://xmlgrid.net converts any of my really complicated xmls in to tree view . I need to build a similar way to view my xmls so it can be used internally in company over web .

I tried to use jsTree but its really constrained the way xml formats . Is there any other way I can easily view xml to a jquery tree ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would convert that XML with something like [xml2json](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/) and then feed it to [jqTree](http://mbraak.github.com/jqTree/). I can't think of a simpler way to do it, and there are considerable [advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615352/xml-and-json-advantages-and-disadvantages) of using JSON over XML. I cant vouch for the speed of it though...

Parse and use. Consider using JSON from the start.