# Why is XML still used for web service responses, even if JSON is better?

Tags: ios, iphone, xml, json

In my experience I have written many clients for servers in IOS. I used both XML and JSON responses. I observed JSON is light weight, bandwidth efficient, parsing time is less compared to XML. But still some of my clients encouraging XML responses instead of JSON.

**Questions:**

1. What is good about XML than using JSON?
2. Why most of the networking architectures dependent on XML responses even JSON  full fill all the requirements?
3. Is there any issues with JSON?

Comment: You could as well ask "why does HTML still exist for web pages?", whereas it's a flawed, damned and inappropriate format. Apart from that, giving opinions is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @H2CO3 I am not very sure why this is off-topic? If you know any strong reason to use xml or flaw's in JSON just share here.

Comment: You might find this useful in understanding why your question is off-topic  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we cannot say json or xml which is superior each having its advantages and disadvantages..
you can just google the differences.
try these links

[XML and JSON -- Advantages and Disadvantages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615352/xml-and-json-advantages-and-disadvantages)

http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-of-XML-over-JSON

may be your clients are used to xml and they don't want to change, or they may have experienced some problems using json

Comment: +1Thanks for reply. Suits for my question